# Reordering text file: Python

Tags: python, pandas, text-files

I have many text files. All of them have the following kind of structure.

textfile.txt

```
id|name|dataType
5|aa|String
4|bb|DateTime
|dd|DateTime
1|cc|DateTime
3|dd|DateTime
```

I would like to read all these text files one by one and reorder them based on their id and rows with no id should be excluded.
After that I would like to get the following:

```
id|name|dataType
1|cc|DateTime
3|dd|DateTime
4|bb|DateTime
5|aa|String
```

Is there any pythonic way to do this?

Comment: @ᴊᴇsᴘᴇʀᴋ.ᴇᴛʜ your modification of the output was incorrect ("*rows with no id should be excluded*")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
(pd.read_csv('textfile.txt', sep='|')
   .loc[lambda d: d['id'].notna()]
   .convert_dtypes()
   .sort_values(by='id')
   .to_csv('out.txt', sep='|', index=False)
)
```

`out.txt`:

```
id|name|dataType
1|cc|DateTime
3|dd|DateTime
4|bb|DateTime
5|aa|String
```